# android/iphone app can steal your contacts and sms?

Tags: iphone, android, contacts, privacy

Can a (jailbroken OR not) smart phone app access your private info, contacts, sms and sends back to collector?

Comment: Strange, why is it "off topic" to ask a question about the capabilities of two smartphone SDKs? I think this is a good question and it had already received some promising answers.

Answer (score 3):

On a stock Android phone, an application can *request* permission to access all of those items.

On a stock iPhone, an application can access contacts, but not SMS etc.

On a jailbroken iPhone, an application can do whatever it wants.

Answer (score 1):

On android an app can steal your information and send them back but when you install them from market you can see which things the app wants access to.

I don't know about the iPhone.